# Proving that $E[XE(Y|X)] = E(XY)$ implies $\text{cov}(X,E(Y|X))=\text{cov}(X,Y)$.

Tags: probability

If you're given that

$$E[XE(Y|X)] = E(XY)$$

then prove that:

$$cov(X,E(Y|X))=cov(X,Y)$$

My first step was to write out the covariances as

$$cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$$

$$cov(X,E(Y|X))=E(XE(Y|X)) - E(X)E(Y|X))$$

then write:

$$E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=E(XE(Y|X)) - E(X)E(Y|X))$$

substitute from the given...

$$E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=E(XY) - E(X)E(Y|X))$$

leaving...

$$E(X)E(Y)=E(X)E(Y|X)$$

I'm stuck here.  I know if $X$ and $Y$ are independent that I can then say that $E(Y|X)=E(Y)$ but, while I suspect they are independent, I don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is here:
$$
\operatorname{cov}(X,E(Y\mid X))=E(XE(Y\mid X)) - E(X)E(Y\mid X))
$$
The final term on the RHS should be $E(X)E[E(Y\mid X)]$, which simplifies to $E(X)E(Y)$.